# FFT, but with a linear wavelength scale

Tags: matlab, fft

When the FFT is performed on a function of time *u* in Matlab, a complex spectrum *uf* is returned. To plot the spectral amplitude *abs(uf)* against its frequency content, a frequency grid can be made to accommodate *uf*. I can associate a wavelength grid with the frequency grid, and plot *uf* against that also. The spacing between each element in the frequency array is constant, but since wavelength ~ 1/frequency, the spacing between each point in the wavelength array varies over the array index. I am curious if there is a way to take the FFT of a function of time to yield a spectrum in wavelength that has constant spacing. Here is my code in Matlab:

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

lam = 800e-9; % Wavelength (m)
c = 3e8; % Light speed (m/s)

nt = 8192; % Temporal grid resolution
T = 400*1e-15; % Temporal grid size (s)
dt = T/nt; % Temporal pixel spacing

df = 1/(nt*dt); % Frequency pixel spacing
ff = [(0:nt/2-1) (-nt/2:-1)]*df; % Frequency grid 
ff = fftshift(ff); 

wav = c./ff; % Wavelength array (spacing is not constant between each element)

for k = 1:nt
    tt(k) = (-nt/2+k-1)*dt; % Time array
    u(k) = cos(2*pi*c/lam*tt(k)); % Function of time
end

%Now I can take FFT:

uf = fftshift(fft(u)); % The spectrum of my function. The FFT has yielded a spectrum associated with a frequency array of linearly spaced elements (ff).
```

Both plots of spectral amplitude vs. wavelength and vs. frequency yield good results.

```
figure(1)
plot(ff,abs(uf)) 
title('Spectral amplitude vs frequency')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Spectral amplitude')

figure(2)
plot(wav,abs(uf))
title('Spectral amplitude vs wavelength')
xlabel('Wavelength (m)')
ylabel('Spectral amplitude');
```

[image]

But my wavelength array does not have constant spacing:

```
figure(3)
plot(ff)
title('Frequency array')
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
xlabel('Index')

figure(4)
plot(wav)
xlim([(nt/2 +1) (nt/2 + 100)])
title('Wavelength array')
ylabel('Wavelength (m)')
xlabel('Index')
```

[image]

Comment: can you more concisely state your problem?

Comment: Why do you need a constant spacing for your wavelength intervals? An FFT is always calculated at fixed frequency intervals, which results in non constant wavelength intervals (`wav = c./ff`). You can interpolate if needed.

Comment: I need a constant wavelength spacing because my generated spectral amplitude will serve as an input to another program which demands constant wavelength spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a linearly spaced wavelength array and interpolate your data to find the linearly spaced y values.